# Django form unknown fields error for forms.py

Tags: python, django

. i have used the debug tool on my vscode to debug the forms.py and my views.py. it returns this.

```
Exception has occurred: ImproperlyConfigured
Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings
```

this is the error i get when i run manage.py runserver
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
   File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in
    inner_run
        self.check(display_num_errors=True)
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 395, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
        return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
        return check_resolver(resolver)
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
        return check_method()
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
        for pattern in self.url_patterns:
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
        return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\crypt\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
        path('', include('cryptdjango.urls'))
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
        urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cryptdjango\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
        from .import views
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cryptdjango\views.py", line 4, in <module>
        from .forms import CreateUserForm
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cryptdjango\forms.py", line 8, in <module>
        class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
      File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\bio\apitests\crypt\cert\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 267, in __new__
        raise FieldError(message)
    django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (lastname, products, title, firstname, phonenumber, country, birth) specified for User
```

This is my settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cryptdjango',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'crypt.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'crypt.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

this is my forms.py i am wondering if i am supposed to add forms to my settings.py , i am really confused. it was working perfectly before i started creating forms

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['country','title','firstname','lastname','birth','email','phonenumber','username','password','products']
```

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import CreateUserForm
from .models import *
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.


def hp(request):
    return render(request, 'cryptyy/hp.html')

def login(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'cryptyy/login.html', context)

def signup(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, 'Account created for ' + user)
            return redirect('login')

    context =  {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'cryptyy/sign-up.html', context)


def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'cryptyy/dashboard.html')
```

Comment: The issue is that you are including some fields that the  diango user form does not have in the form.py if you want to add the form then you need to pass two different forms from your views.py to fronr end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please in the forms.py the only accepted fields by django user are the one I listed below, if you wish to have extra fields sent to the frontend, then you have to make a profile model and make a form for the same for the extra fields

In the output logs you gave I think you can see the fields that you are told you cannot have in the last line

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name','last_name','email','username','password']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the fields you want your form to have do not exist in your User Model. I would suggest

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = '__all__'
```

And see all the fields you're getting in the form then. 
Once all the fields are rendered in the final form, you can choose the fields you wanna show to the end user accordingly.